# How to change the field datetime without time in database H2

Tags: database, h2

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `operation` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `finish_time` datetime NOT NULL
);
```

And for this table, you need to insert the value from the finish_time to the start_time. By transforming a field without time.

For example: "2018-02-02 10:10:10" => "2018-02-02 00:00:00"

I know how to do this for MySQL:

```
update operation
set start_time = DATE_FORMAT(finish_time,'%y-%m-%d')
where start_time is null;
```

but there is no such function DATE_FORMAT in H2.

How to execute this query for database H2?

Comment: Shouldn't the data type of `start_time` be `DATE` instead of `DATETIME`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip the time information by using `CAST()`. For example:

```
update operation
set start_time = cast(finish_time as date)
where start_time is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using FORMATDATETIME()

```
update operation
set start_time = FORMATDATETIME((finish_time, '%y-%m-%d')
where start_time is null;
```